# Delphi 2010 How to add break point in Classes.pas

Tags: multithreading, delphi, pascal

I want to add a break point in TThread class ,function ThreadProc which in Classes.pas.
but i click and run the break point has a cross on it, it doesnt work.

i have a class has a TThread member , it construt in initialization and destory in finalization
but when it go into destroy method, it doesnt go to DoTerminate procedure which i override , but when
i put the destory procedure  out of the finalization section ,it works and no memory leak, it confuse
me, so i want to add break point in classes.pas to check out why this happened?

I tried to print the thread properties to find out the reason, and i found out the Terminated property is True but the Finished property is false, although I thought in Destroy inherited, it will terminate the thread, and also i put the destory out of the finalization section, the Finished property does become Ture ,and it go to DoTerminate procedure successfully
Its really Confuse me, hope someone can help me to figure it out .

Sorry about my English and Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you are building in debug configuration. Also go to Project > Options > Delphi Compiler > Compiling > Debugging and make sure there is a checkbox next to "Use debug .dcus".

Comment: `DoTerminate()` is called immediate after `Execute()` exits. Make sure your `Execute()` isn't deadlocking during shutdown trying to do something that depends on the main thread mesaage loop, like `Synchronize()`, etc.